# Unchecked cast on a Map<String, Object> (JSON converted to Map with Jackson)

Tags: java, json, jackson, unchecked-cast

In Java 8, I want to convert a JSON string to a map, and apply "complex" transformations to the keys. **As an example**, that "complex" transformation will simply be a lower case transformation.
Values in the input JSON could be strings or nested JSON objects.
My code is actually working, but I struggle to fix an `unchecked cast` warning.

#### Example

Example JSON input (`String`) :

```
{
    "Key1": "value1",
    "Key2": {
        "Key2.1": "value2.1"
    }
}
```

Desired output (`Map`) :

```
"key1" -> "value1"
"key2" ->
    "key2.1" -> "value2.1"
```

#### 1. JSON String -> Map

For that part, I used Jackson (2.9.8) and defined the following function :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

Map<String, Object> convertJsonStringToMap(String json) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeReference type = new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){};
    return mapper.readValue(json, type);
}
```

Since values can be strings or JSON objects, the return type of that function is `Map<String, Object>`. Note also that
`readValue` (in `ObjectMapper` class) uses generics, its signature is :

```
<T> T readValue(String content, TypeReference valueTypeRef)
```

#### 2. Map -> Map with transformed keys (example : lower case)

I defined the following function :

```
Map<String, Object> transformKeys(Map<String, Object> map) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>(map.size());

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        if (value instanceof Map) {
            value = transformKeys((Map<String, Object>) value);
        }
        // toLowerCase() is the transformation here (example), but I could have used something else
        result.put(entry.getKey().toLowerCase(), value);
    }

    return result;
}
```

To handle nested maps, this function is recursive. But since it takes a `Map<String, Object>` as parameter,
 I must cast `value` to `Map<String, Object>` to call the method recursively.

#### 3. Putting all together

```
String json = "{\"Key1\": \"value1\", \"Key2\": { \"Key2.1\": \"value2.1\" }}";
Map<String, Object> initialMap = convertJsonStringToMap(json);
Map transformedMap = transformKeys(initialMap);
System.out.println(transformedMap);
```

This code works, and prints, as expected :

> {key1=value1, key2={key2.1=value2.1}}

But this line in `transformKeys` function :

```
value = transformKeys((Map<String, Object>) value);
```

produces a warning :

```
[WARNING] App.java:[29,74] unchecked cast
    required: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>
    found:    java.lang.Object
```

The warning is clear and I understand it (the compiler cannot know if `value` is really an instance of `Map<String, Object>`), but is there a way to get rid of it?

(No `@SuppressWarnings` please, nor `-Xlint:none`) :D

I feel like returning a `Map<String, Object>` from `convertJsonStringToMap` is
not the cleanest way to convert JSON String to a Map, but I can't find an other way to do it with Jackson.

Comment: No, there's no way. That's what SuppressWarnings is for.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your answer. Is there really no solution to avoid writing this cast? I feel like using `Object`s as the `Map` values is the real cause of the problem, that's why I wrote the complete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Object` as `Map` value because it could be another `Map`, `List` or `primitive` (`String`, `Integer`, etc.). `Jackson` allows also to manipulate `JSON` using `JsonNode` types. We need to traverse `JSON object` but also `JSON array` (you forgot about it). In that case we need to:

- Deserialise `JSON` to `JsonNode`.
- Traverse it using `JsonNode` `API`.
- Convert to the `Map`

Simple implementation:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "{\"Key1\": \"value1\", \"Key2\": { \"Key2.1\": \"value2.1\" }, \"Key3\":[{\"pRiMe\":11}]}";
        Map<String, Object> map = convertJsonStringToMap(json);

        System.out.println(map);
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> convertJsonStringToMap(String json) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json);
        transformKeys(node);

        TypeReference mapType = new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        };

        return mapper.convertValue(node, mapType);
    }

    private static void transformKeys(JsonNode parent) {
        if (parent.isObject()) {
            ObjectNode node = (ObjectNode) parent;

            List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
            node.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(names::add);

            names.forEach(name -> {
                JsonNode item = node.remove(name);
                transformKeys(item);
                node.replace(name.toLowerCase(), item);
            });
        } else if (parent.isArray()) {
            ArrayNode array = (ArrayNode) parent;
            array.elements().forEachRemaining(JsonApp::transformKeys);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{key1=value1, key2={key2.1=value2.1}, key3=[{prime=11}]}
```

We got rid of unsafe casting and our implementation is more concise.